# Cant use space from a mounted disk in a debian GCP VM

Tags: linux, debian, disk, storage

I mounted a SD disk to my Google cloud VM running debian 11. It' mounted on /mnt, and it has 100gb of free space.

But when i try to install anything in the VM, it says i dont have free space. Somehow i need to tell to the vm to use that disk storage, but i don't know how, im a new linux user.

Can someone help me here? The print below shows the situation. I'm listing every command i used to mount the disk below too.
Thanks

[image]

```
## Format disk
sudo mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard /dev/sdb

## Make disk directory
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/disks/disk1

## Using mount tool
sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/DEVICE_NAME /mnt/disks/disk1

## Read and write permissions to every user
sudo chmod a+w /mnt/disks/disk1
```

Comment: Needed space is under /var/cache/… while you provide space under /mnt

Comment: You need space. Period! Take a look at `/` 100% usage. Move data from `/` to `/mnt` and then it will work.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it